# Old and outmoded politicians

Tags: word-usage

Give me adjectives for politicians who are old, not belonging to the radically transformed world of  our  times, and therefore not fit to rule in this transformed world

Comment: The standard cliche is [***political dinosaurs***](https://www.freemalaysiatoday.com/category/nation/2022/02/16/political-dinosaurs-holding-back-rise-of-new-leaders-says-analyst/), but this is effectively an Off Topic open-ended "list-type" question. But it's a bit simple-minded to assume that having lived more years makes you less competent than the latest generation of hotheaded malcontents. Some young people have very reactionary politics, and some old people are truly radical. It's *attitude*, not *age*, that matters here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - _But it's a bit simple-minded to assume that having lived more years makes you less competent_ It's not just 'a bit simple minded'; it's utterly idiotic.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. I offer a suggestion on your style: *Give me adjectives….” is worded quite bluntly, and so it reads like a command. It would suggest to many readers that you hold the people whom you address in contempt. People here on ELL don’t exist merely to serve you. We know you are likely an English learner, so we’d doubt you meant an insult. You might reword your request something like “What are some adjectives…”

Comment: *Outmoded* is fine, but maybe you want something ruder? Are you looking for a neutral/descriptive term or an insult?

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious to me would be the compound adjective '*out-of-touch*', or '*out of touch with the modern world*', if you wanted to be more specific - most people use it without such a qualification because it is tacit.

This focuses on their disconnect and inability to keep up with progress, rather than just the fact they are old. Calling someone a *dinosaur, antiquated, superannuated* etc works fine as an insult, but is indefensible against accusations of ageism.